# Javassist adding annotation to method argument

Tags: parameters, annotations, javassist

Read this [answer](https://community.jboss.org/message/613628) on the jboss community regarding adding an annotation to a parameter in a method.  Stuck at getting the parameter or in Javassist terms the attribute.

Given class XYZ:

```
public class XYZ {
   public void changes(String whatever, Integer flag) {
   }
}
```

With the following code:
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass clazz = pool.get(XYZ.class.getName());

```
CtMethod m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("changes");
CtClass[] parameters = m.getParameterTypes();  // shows 2 parameter (one String, other Integer)

AttributeInfo paramAtrributeInfo = m.getMethodInfo().getAttribute("whatever");
```

**paramAttributeInfo** is null.  I see 2 attributes when debugging but these have concrete calls LocalVariableAttribute and LineNumberAttribute.

Can't get a handle (attribute) to add my parameter annotation to.  Ideas?

Comment: Of course, it is `null`. The fact that you want to add an annotation implies that the annotation does not exist yet. So even if you replace the string `"whatever"` with the correct attribute name for parameter annotations it would return a non-`null` value only if another parameter annotation exists. That’s far away from a safe bet.

Comment: @Holger, totally right.  Found code (random project) that is doing something similar.  Creating a ParameterAnnotationsAttribute, adding the annotation then adding that attribute to the method.  Will report back if that works.

Comment: @Holger, thanks again.  Hadn't gotten my head around the way Javassist works.  Creating a ParameterAnnotationsAttribute (PAA) then an Annotation and adding it to the PAA works great.